# How can I enter an already hashed password in OpenLDAP with phpLDAPadmin?

Tags: php, ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

I set up a small OpenLDAP server with phpLDAPadmin to manage our users for multiple services. Unfortunately, I have not found a template with which users can enter/register themselves in the LDAP (but that's another problem). So currently I register them manually via phpLDAPadmin; the structure ist very simple: I have only "ou=users" with all users (cn="...") under it.

But no matter what I try: I can't enter the Passwords in a hashed form! My current method is that users send me their passwords and I enter it with selecting "MD5", but I don't want to know the clear passwords. And - of course - some users are not comfortable with it.

Eg.:
The password should be: PasswordTest1
The hash of it is: 0f9046b07df8b8424d374d865a08b04a
I tried to select "clear" in phpLDAPadmin and entered: {MD5}0f9046b07df8b8424d374d865a08b04a

But the user can't login with his password "PasswordTest1"...

Is it possible to do this? Do you know, what I am doing wrong?
Thx!

[Add-User-Window in phpLDAPadmin; I can select "MD5", "clear" and more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtkKj.png)

Answer (score 0):

How are they generating their hashed passwords? I'd recommend they use the slappasswd utility:

```
# slappasswd -h {MD5}
New password: 
Re-enter new password: 
{MD5}+mpaMiTX2mbZ4L3sJfYs8A==
```

This is part of the slapd package, so either they install it themselves, or they come to your workstation to enter their passwords when you run it. I haven't  used php ldap admin but I think they might be generating their passwords incorrectly?